# Can I create a static Cython library using distutils?

Tags: python, static-libraries, cython, distutils

I'd like to build a static Cython library using distutils. I don't care about having it be a true Python extension module that can be import'ed. I just want to compile the code and put the objects in a static library. The code to create a dynamic library is very simple,

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
   cmdclass = {'build_ext':build_ext},
   ext_modules = [Extension("test",["test.pyx"])]
)
```

Is there a simple way to make it static instead?

Comment: How will you import the library from Python if it's static ? Do you want to statically link your Python interpreter with it ?

Comment: I don't need to import the library from Python. This is being used to call Python code from a C program. My program will be linked dynamically with libpython.

Answer (score 2):

Distutils is very limited and not set up for static builds.  I would advise you to use something else to compile the static library part of your project.

If your use case is to call into Cython code from other C code, then you want to use the [`public` or `api` declarations](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#using-cython-declarations-from-c) along with your `cdef` declared functions and variables in your Cython code.  Cython will allow the so-declared objects to be called from external C code, and it will generate a `.h` file alongside the `.c` file for you.

Answer (score 1):

Fyi, this works using `numpy distutils`, but obviously is nowhere near the simplicity or probably portability of the original code for a shared library,

```
from Cython.Compiler.Main import compile
from numpy.distutils.misc_util import Configuration

compile('test.pyx')
config = Configuration(...)
config.add_installed_library('test',
                         ['test.c'],
                         'test',
                         {'include_dirs':[get_python_inc()]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a `sources`, `include_dirs` and `build_dir` in your setup.py, this is how you can build a static library

```
from distutils.ccompiler import new_compiler 
from sysconfig import get_paths 
import os

project_name = "slimey_project"
source = ['source1.c']
include_dirs = ['include']
build_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'build')

class StaticLib(Command): 
    description = 'build static lib' 
    user_options = [] # do not remove, needs to be stubbed out! 
    python_info = get_paths() 

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        # Create compiler with default options
        c = new_compiler()

        # Optionally add include directories etc.
        for d in include_dirs:
            c.add_include_dir(d)

        c.add_include_dir(self.python_info['include'])
        # Compile into .o files
        objects = c.compile(sources)

        # Create static or shared library
        c.create_static_lib(objects, project_name, output_dir=build_dir)
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/udnaan/d549950a33fd82d13f9e6ba4aae82964

Comment: Hi Adnan, could you please elaborate on how to use this? I'm new to compiling cython, could you please provide a basic example? Thanks

Comment: If you save this file (setup.py) in a directory, create a source1.c in the same directory, and run python setup.py, it will create the static lib.